# Suggested way to structure Firestore database for deeply nested set of spreadsheet like objects

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

My application is used for creating production budgets for complex projects (construction, media productions etc.)

The structure of the budget is as follows:
The budget contains "sections",
the sections contain "accounts"
the accounts contains "subaccounts"
the subaccounts contain line items.
   Line items have a number of fields, (units, rate, currency, tax etc.) and a calculated total

Or perhaps using Firestore to do these cascading calculations is the wrong approach? I should just load a single complex budget document into my app, do all the cacluations and updates on the clients, and then write back the entire budget as a single document when the user presses "save budget"?

Certain fields in line items may have alpha numeric codes which represent numeric values, which a user can use instead of a hard-coded number, e.g. user can enter "=build-weeks" and define that with a formula that evaluates to say "7" which is then used in the calculation of a total.

Line items bubble up their totals, so subaccounts have total equal to the sum of their line items,
Accounts total equals the total of their subaccounts, 
sections total equals sum of accounts totals, 
and budget total is total of section totals.

The question si how to aggregate into this data into documents comprising the budget.
Budgets may be sort of long, say 5,000 linesitems or more in total.  Single accounts may have hundreds of line items.

Users will most likely look at a all of the line items for a given account, so it occurred to me 
to make individual documents for sections, accounts and subaccounts, and make line items a map within a sub account.

The problem main concern I have with this approach is that when the user changes, say the exchange rate of currency of a line item, or changes the calculated value of a named value like "build-weeks" I will ahve to retrieve all the individual line items containing that curency or named value, recalculate the total, and then bubble up the changes through the hierarchy.

This seems not that complicated if each line item is its own document, I can just search the collection for the presence of the code in question, recalculate the line item, and use a cloud function to bubble up teh changes maybe.

But if all the lineitems are contained in an array of maps within each subaccount map item,
it seems like it will be quite tedious to find and change them when necessary..

On the other hand -- keeping these documents so small seems like a lot of document reads when somebody is reviewing a budget, or say, printing it, If somebody just clicks on a bunch of accounts, it might be 100's of reads per click to retrieve all the line items and hundreds or a thousand writes when somebody changes the value of a often used named value like "build-weeks".

Does anybody have any thoughts on the obvious "right" answer to this? Or does it just depend on what I want to optimize for - firestore costs, responsiveness of app, complexity of code?

Answer (score 0):

From my stand point, there is no obvious answer to your problem and indeed it does depend on what you want to optimize for.

However there are a few points that you need to consider on your decision:

- Documents in Firestore have a limit of 1Mb/Document;
- Documents in Firestore have a limit of 20000 fields;
- Queries are shallow, so you don't get data from subcollections on the same query;

For considerations 1 and 2, this means that if you choose the design you database to a big document containing everything, even though you said that your app will have lots of data, I doubt that it will be more than the limits mentioned, still, do consider those. Also, how necessary is it to get all the data at once, this could represent performance and user battery/data usage issues (if you are making a mobile app).

For consideration 3, it means that you would have to make many reads if you choose to get all the data for your sections divided in subdocuments, this will mean more cost to you but better performance for users.

To make the right call on this problem I suggest that you talk to possible users of your solution and understand the problem that you are trying to fix and what they expect of the app. Also, it might be interesting to take a look at the [How to Structure Your Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=5) and [Maps, Arrays and Subcollections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=4) videos, as they explain in a more visual way how Firestore behaves and it could be helpful to antecipate problems that the approach you choose could cause.

Hope I was able to help with these considerations.